# Fetch all Column Statistics using Single Query Hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, qubole, hive-query

I understand that all the column statistics can be computed for a Hive table using the command-

```
ANALYZE TABLE Table1 COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Then Specific column level stats can be fetched through the command -

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED Table1.Column1;
....
DESCRIBE FORMATTED Table1.Columnn;
```

Is it possible to fetch all column stats using a single command?

Comment: The information can be fetched from metastore db table TAB_COL_STATS.